# Ordenar 2 colunas de uma vez - Asp Mvc + FluentNhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, classificação, fluent-nhibernate

Bom dia!

Gostaria de saber como faço para ordenar duas colunas de uma vez em uma consulta de forma que fique, no meu caso, 1º em ordem decrescente de data porém em ordem alfabética.

```
        public IList<Analise> ListaTodosOrdenado()
    {
        using (ISession _session = FHibernateHelper.AbreSession())
        {

            var analises = _session.QueryOver<Analise>()                      
                                 .JoinQueryOver(p => p.MateriaPrima)
                                 .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                                 .List();

            var a = analises.OrderByDescending(d => d.DataCadastro).OrderBy(n=>n.MateriaPrima.Nome);


                return (analises);
        }
    }
```

Nessas linhas de código, ele 1º ordena por data, porém a segunda ordenação sobrepõe a 1ª.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4658205/2221388 Veja se isso possa te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, deu certo!!

Answer (score 1):

O que você deve usar é a função `ThenBy` como no exemplo

```
MyList
.OrderByDescending(p => p.ToDate)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.Number)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.RunDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```